# Copyindex in deploying dashboard resources Azure ARM

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am deploying a custom Azure Dashboard with a tile that makes use of a resource.
To call the resource I use following code

```
"[resourceId(parameters('analysisServiceResourceGroup'), '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisServiceName'))]"
```

But in one of the tiles I need multiple resources so I tried something out to make a parameter file with following value

```
 "analysisService": {
        "value": [
            {
                "ResourceGroup": "RG",
                "Name": "analysis1",
                "Color": "#47BDF5"
            },
            {
                "ResourceGroup": "RG",
                "Name": "analysis2",
                "Color": "#7E58FF"
            },
            {
                "ResourceGroup": "RG",
                "Name": "analysis3",
                "Color": "#EB9371"
            }
        ]
    },
```

In my dashboard template i use following code to get the name and resource group.

```
 "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Name)]"
```

The problem I got at the moment my copy object is not placed in the right place. I got this error

> 'The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.'"

This says that my copy index block is not used in the right resource bracelet but I don't know where i can place this copy Index , tried to put this in every possible place where the copy index can access this but nothing works does anyone know what I do wrong or what I do wrong. It may be possible that copyindex doesn't work inside a dashboard resource.

Code

```
 "12": {
            "position": {
              "x": 12,
              "y": 9,
              "colSpan": 6,
              "rowSpan": 4
            },
            "metadata": {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "name": "sharedTimeRange",
                  "isOptional": true
                },
                {
                  "name": "options",
                  "value": {
                    "charts": [
                      {
                        "metrics": [
                          {
                            "name": "CurrentUserSessions",
                            "resourceMetadata": {
                              "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Name)]"
                            },
                            "aggregationType": 1,


"copy": {
                "name": "AnalysisServiceCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]"
              },

                          }
                        ],
                        "title": "Avg Current User Sessions for analysis1, analysis1, and analysis1",
                        "visualization": {
                          "chartType": 2,
                          "legend": {
                            "isVisible": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "hideSubtitle": false
                          },
                          "axis": {
                            "x": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 2,
                              "min": 1546508634047,
                              "max": 1546595034047
                            },
                            "y": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 1
                            }
                          },
                          "timeBrushEnable": false
                        },
                        "itemDataModel": {
                          "id": "3464BA29-9AF2-4EAE-9CF4-A246059DDF46",
                          "chartHeight": 1,
                          "metrics": [
                            {
                              "id": {
                                "resourceDefinition": {
                                  "id": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Name)]"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                  "id": "CurrentUserSessions",
                                  "displayName": "Current User Sessions"
                                },
                                "namespace": {
                                  "name": "microsoft.analysisservices/servers"
                                }
                              },
                              "metricAggregation": 4,
                              "color": "[parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Color]"

,
 "copy": {
                "name": "AnalysisServiceCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]"
              },

                            }
                          ],
                          "priorPeriod": false,
                          "horizontalBars": true,
                          "showOther": false,
                          "aggregation": 1,
                          "palette": "multiColor",
                          "jsonDefinitionId": "59DCE403-7D8D-4E9F-9CDA-7AE7AC9D9220",
                          "version": {
                            "major": 1,
                            "minor": 0,
                            "build": 0
                          },
                          "filters": {
                            "filterType": 0,
                            "id": "C81486BB-3934-48C7-9251-A4EE633DB2BB",
                            "OperandFilters": [],
                            "LogicalOperator": 0
                          },
                          "yAxisOptions": {
                            "options": 1
                          },
                          "title": "Avg Current User Sessions for analysis1, analysis1, and analysis1",
                          "titleKind": "Auto",
                          "visualization": {
                            "chartType": 2,
                            "legend": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "position": 2,
                              "hideSubtitle": false
                            },
                            "axis": {
                              "x": {
                                "isVisible": true,
                                "axisType": 2,
                                "min": 1546508634047,
                                "max": 1546595034047
                              },
                              "y": {
                                "isVisible": true,
                                "axisType": 1
                              }
                            },
                            "timeBrushEnable": false
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "v2charts": true,
                    "version": 1
                  },
                  "isOptional": true
                }
              ],
              "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MonitorChartPart",
              "settings": {
                "content": {
                  "options": {
                    "charts": [
                      {
                        "metrics": [
                          {
                            "name": "CurrentUserSessions",
                            "resourceMetadata": {
                              "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Name)]"
                            },
                            "aggregationType": 1

,
 "copy": {
                "name": "AnalysisServiceCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]"
              },
                          }
                        ],
                        "title": "Avg Current User Sessions for analysis1, analysis1, and analysis1",
                        "visualization": {
                          "chartType": 2,
                          "legend": {
                            "isVisible": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "hideSubtitle": false
                          },
                          "axis": {
                            "x": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 2,
                              "min": 1546508634047,
                              "max": 1546595034047
                            },
                            "y": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 1
                            }
                          },
                          "timeBrushEnable": false
                        },
                        "itemDataModel": {
                          "id": "3464BA29-9AF2-4EAE-9CF4-A246059DDF46",
                          "chartHeight": 1,
                          "metrics": [
                            {
                              "id": {
                                "resourceDefinition": {
                                  "id": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Name)]"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                  "id": "CurrentUserSessions",
                                  "displayName": "Current User Sessions"
                                },
                                "namespace": {
                                  "name": "microsoft.analysisservices/servers"
                                }
                              },
                              "metricAggregation": 4,
                              "color": "[parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex()].Color]"

,
 "copy": {
                "name": "AnalysisServiceCopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]"
              },
                            }
                          ],
                          "priorPeriod": false,
                          "horizontalBars": true,
                          "showOther": false,
                          "aggregation": 1,
                          "palette": "multiColor",
                          "jsonDefinitionId": "59DCE403-7D8D-4E9F-9CDA-7AE7AC9D9220",
                          "version": {
                            "major": 1,
                            "minor": 0,
                            "build": 0
                          },
                          "filters": {
                            "filterType": 0,
                            "id": "C81486BB-3934-48C7-9251-A4EE633DB2BB",
                            "OperandFilters": [],
                            "LogicalOperator": 0
                          },
                          "yAxisOptions": {
                            "options": 1
                          },
                          "title": "Avg Current User Sessions for analysis1, analysis1, and analysis1",
                          "titleKind": "Auto",
                          "visualization": {
                            "chartType": 2,
                            "legend": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "position": 2,
                              "hideSubtitle": false
                            },
                            "axis": {
                              "x": {
                                "isVisible": true,
                                "axisType": 2,
                                "min": 1546508634047,
                                "max": 1546595034047
                              },
                              "y": {
                                "isVisible": true,
                                "axisType": 1
                              }
                            },
                            "timeBrushEnable": false
                          }
                        },
                        "disablePinning": true
                      }
                    ],
                    "v2charts": true,
                    "version": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "copy": {
            "name": "AnalysisServiceCopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]"
          },
```

Comment: you need this loop only for the metrics array, right?

Comment: yes , i tried putting my copy resource only in the metrics but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, as a general rule, you can only use copy loop to create arrays, not object, so to construct you metrics array you would do something like this:

```
"charts": [
    {
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "metrics",
                "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "CurrentUserSessions",
                    "resourceMetadata": {
                        "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].Name)]"
                    },
                    "aggregationType": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "title": "Avg Current User Sessions for analysis1, analysis1, and analysis1",
        "visualization": { redacted for brievity },
        "itemDataModel": { redacted for brievity },
        "disablePinning": true
    }
],
```

you would need to do this everywhere you need to construct an array. as a workaround (if they are identical) you can use the same construct to create a variable and use that variable:

```
"variables": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "metrics",
            "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]",
            "input": {
                "name": "CurrentUserSessions",
                "resourceMetadata": {
                    "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].ResourceGroup, '/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].Name)]"
                },
                "aggregationType": 1
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

the above will create a variable called "metrics" which you can use anywhere in the template like so:

```
"[variables('metrics')]"
```

Comment: YES that seems the way to do it, will try it asap.
How do you call the metric variable inside your template.
Like this ?
"[variables('copy').'metrics']

Comment: sorry, forgot to specify that. its just `"[variables('metrics')]"`

Comment: No that doesn't do it
inside my template i used it like this :  `"metrics":"[variables('metrics')]",`
but I get an "undefined variable reference metric"

Comment: it should be, this means you made a mistake somewhere, there is no reason this wouldnt work inside any element

Comment: I post the code that I use with your solution. But can't seem to find the error.

Comment: can you post your whole template somewhere? I dont see any problem with the snippet you posted

Comment: The error doesn't come from any other part of the code (1.5k lines of code :(  )
I also tried your first solution and this works flawless , but changing just these lines (see answer) gave me the error on the variable part

Comment: sorry, but I cant really tell you what is wrong without looking at the whole template, can you at least show your variables section as it is (the WHOLE variables section)?

Comment: no idea, this looks fine. cant help you unless you can show me a repro

Comment: I guess I just will stick with your first solution which works flawless. And will debug this step per step.
Thnx for the help !!!

Answer (score 0):

@4c74356b41

I tried it like this , I directly get an green error line beneath copy that this varbiable never is used.

```
"variables": {
"copy": [
  {
    "name": "metrics",
    "count": "[length(parameters('analysisService'))]",
    "input": {
      "name": "qpu_metric",
      "resourceMetadata": {
        "resourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].ResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers', parameters('analysisService')[copyIndex('metrics')].Name)]"
      },
      "aggregationType": 1
    }
  }
]
```

},

In my code I call the variable like this

```
  "charts": [
                          {
                            "metrics" : "[variables('metrics')]",
                            "title": "Avg QPU",
                            "visualization": {
```

Comment: green line is totally expected, intellisense isnt smart enough

Comment: Doesn't makes sense that i call the variable something like this 
"[variables('copy').metrics]",

Comment: you cannot call it like that, because `copy` isnt a variable name, its a function that returns values